# Error 500 Trying to Connect to NetSuite RESTlet using C#

Tags: c#, rest, netsuite

I'm trying to build a connector between a credit card processor and a client's NetSuite account to help automate their reconciliation process. Not having any trouble pulling info from their card processor, except occasionally when it has its own error 500. Still trying to find a way to better handle it than what I'm doing.

Anyway, the problem is occurring when I try to connect to the RESTlet in their NetSuite account. I can't seem to get it to properly connect, and all I get are error 500 responses. The problem doesn't seem to be the RESTlet as I can communicate with it fine when using tools like "Send HTTP Tool" to test it out. This is the code I'm using currently:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String content = jss.Serialize(rd);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.nsURL);
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.ContentLength = content.Length;
req.Method = "POST";
WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
headers.Add("User-Agent-X", "SuiteScript-Call");
headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("NLAuth nlauth_account={0},nlauth_email={1},nlauth_signature={2},nlauth_role={3}",
    this.nsAccount, this.nsEmail, this.nsPassword, this.nsRole));
req.Headers = headers;

using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
{
    requestWriter.Write(content);
}

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); // error occurs here
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    String response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

And this is the error recorded:

```
[System.Net.WebException] The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

The error occurs at the point I try to retrieve the response from the HttpWebRequest object. I have tried sending the data instead as a byte array, but that causes a different error at the point I actually write the data to the connection. The RESTlet is also setup to log the data it receives upon being called, but this error is occurring before the RESTlet function can even be triggered.

I've spent too much time trying various different "fixes" to get this to work with no luck.

**---- EDIT ----**

Forgot to mention that I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Pro and targeting .NET 4.

Comment: A 500 error is pretty vague.  Have you tried turning on detailed errors to get a better idea of what the error is?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to "turn on detailed errors" in a console application, but I dug a little further into the error after setting a break point and this is about all there is to show...

`Error Type : System.Net.WebException || 
Error Msg : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. || 
Status : ProtocolError || 
Status Code : InternalServerError || 
Status Description : Internal Server Error`

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley Thanks for sharing some restlet code in c#, can you please help me to connect to netsuite. i would appreciate if you can share with me some sample code of restlet in c#